# coverage java tool

Tags: java, code-coverage

I'm wrintting java tests to control the GUI application, and I'm searching a tool to cover the java test , what is your recommandation ? 
which tool is usually used to cover java tests ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329/what-is-your-favourite-code-coverage-tools-free-and-non-free (although that is a fairly old thread); see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904571/code-coverage-tools-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend taking a look at [Code Pro tools](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/index.html). It's for Eclipse. And it contains a lot more than code coverage, it is code analyzer, junit test generator, dependency analyzer and so on...

Answer (score 6):

I recommend [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) for measuring test coverage. You can plug it into ant, maven, hudson, eclipse etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/), it creates nice reports, and is easy to use in conjunction with junit, using ant or maven.

A great tool for reporting is [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/), which integrates coverage tests, but also tools like checkstyle, findbugs, and provides a nice interface to analyse the outputs. It is also very easy to setup, definitively worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/sonar-to-manage-unit-tests-and-improve-code-coverage/), see the hyperlink for how it shows code coverage (apart from doing many other handy things).

Comment: +1 Sonar isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it can do the job and *much, much more*.